Offsets and label creation for object detection training/inference
I am new to object detection. I know that in object detection anchors are used for detecting objects in the feature map using offsets instead of predicting actual location of the object w.r.t input image space. I want to understand how the labels are created in feature space.
I have some example labels created for Faster-RCNN, but I am not sure how to how to use those labels for YOLO-v5.
The example input is shape is 256256, with stride 4 the feature map size will be 6464. Lets consider the target objects are squire shaped which just varies in size and there is no aspect ratio. For a target bounding box centerX = 25, centerY = 50, and size of object = 10. Let's consider the 2 anchors with sizes 10 and 20.
Now for Faster-RCNN offset = stride/2
In the YOLOv5 github repo(https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/blob/c0380fd85549c8b315bb1fb2f423f9297e9744ec/models/yolo.py#L109) is saw below code
if not self.training:  # inference
if self.dynamic or self.grid[i].shape[2:4] != x[i].shape[2:4]:
    self.grid[i], self.anchor_grid[i] = self._make_grid(nx, ny, i)

xy, wh, conf = x[i].sigmoid().split((2, 2, self.nc + 1), 4)
xy = (xy * 2 + self.grid[i]) * self.stride[i]  # xy
wh = (wh * 2) ** 2 * self.anchor_grid[i]  # wh
y = torch.cat((xy, wh, conf), 4)

Now can someone help me in understanding, how the labels for training/inference will be created for both Faster-RCNN and YOLO-v5? For the bounding box example, I have given above the labels are created for YOLO-v5 based on above inference code ?
